# What kind of rock would be ideal for building a cistern?

Tags: technology, water

You are forced to build cisterns on a large scale to save rainwater. You can only use hand tools. There is no electricity and no power tools. What rock are you looking for to hew the cistern out of and why?

Comment: As phrased now, this is a "building" problem, not a worldbuilding one. And we answer only the latter.

Comment: VTO: border to a storybased question but it can be answered with science and improves realism of a setting. Not much different from bootstraping technologes questions which we have all sorts of. Technolgy in the case is simple - to store water. 2OP u can improve q with  environment where things do happen, whats available, as it somwhat strange problem. So as large scale is how much - a lake?

Comment: @MolbOrg, do you realize that you are voting to reopen yet you are asking for those very details which the question is lacking and for the lack of which it has been closed?

Comment: @L.Dutch First thing I noticed was mod solo, which provoces unhealthy behaviours like jumping in with answers, before our best mod apply his migth. U may notice I wrote the comment thinking it was opinion/story reason, which I would choose in the case if, and noticed it wasn't the case later. Details asked are improvement, and it can be seen in Willk's answer which is 8/10. If size is a lake then I have an option if it is less then not interested. // yes didn't notice the reason, have no problem to admit that, but it does not change the mater, it is okayish q, and we lost another wb user

Comment: Hand tools only, you are limited to Limestone, Sandstone, or similar very soft rocks. *much* easier to make your own rock, from clay(bricks) or if you can from cement

Comment: "On a large scale"? Okay, you don't want to build a cistern, you want to build *a dam*. Dirt will work in a pinch, but just about any rock will do. Line the face with clay or maybe even pitch, if necessary (or just mud, and anyway, most rocks won't permit so much seepage as to matter). Power tools or electricity are not needed; just look at what the ancient Romans and Egyptians did without such.

Answer (score 4):

**Clay**.

[image: cistern]

https://news.virginia.edu/content/newly-uncovered-cistern-sheds-light-universitys-original-firefighting-plan

Carving a vessel out of solid rock is a bad idea.  What if it cracks when you put it in the ground!  Carving rocks is hard.

If you have a choice, dig a hole in a good place, cover the bottom with impermeable clay. then line the hole with bricks or stone.  Then cover the walls with more clay.  It is less work than chipping out a boulder.  It can be repaired with more clay.  It is easy to bring the stones and clay one small load at a time.

---

If that is no good, then the answer is: whatever rock occupies the place where your cistern will be.  Your cistern needs to be sited according to water availability and your needs - close to buildings that might catch fire or at the bottom of a natural rain catchment.  You will dig it out.  You will choose a place where you can dig and where a cistern can be.  I suspect that even if you find a rock that you can hollow out, that just saves you the brick and stone from method 1.  You will still need to waterproof the walls with clay or plaster.

Comment: Hand tools, large scale - hard stone is stroken out completly, not an option. So not any, only soft ones. But yeah good old clay and digging if such option available, or finding naturaly occuring depression and work with it